# Why do I either lag or keep walking or jumping after my finger's off the key in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why do I either lag or keep walking or jumping after my finger's off the key in Minecraft? When I click W to walk or SPACE to jump most of the time it won't walk for a second, then keep walking or jumping after my finger is off of the key. I've had this issue for a month or two and I can't figure out what's wrong. When I connect a Bluetooth Xbox controller it works fine, but it's a hassle to use all of the time. And I don't always have access to one.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard doesn't send the pressed keys immediately (but it has a buffer memory), so it still sends from the buffer after the keys are no longer pressed. It often happens with wireless keyboards with the battery almost exhausted. Test with a wired or another keyboard.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times and nothing works, I've gotten multiple new keyboards and it still does not work.